# jQuery highlight table row

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to highlight a table row on mouse over. Seems like an easy enough thing to do, right? Especially using jQuery. But alas, I'm not so lucky.

I've tested different solutions for highlighting a table row, but nothing seem to work  :-(

I have tested the following scripts:

```
// TEST one    
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

  jQuery("#storeListTable tr").mouseover(function () { 
    $(this).parents('#storeListTable tr').toggleClass("highlight"); 
    alert('test'); // Just to test the mouseover event works
  }); 

});

//TEST 2
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

   $("#storeListTable tbody tr").hover( 
     function() {  // mouseover 
          $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
     }, 
     function() {  // mouseout 
          $(this).removeClass('highlight'); 
     } 
   );
});
```

**This is my HTML code**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
  <title>Title</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/storeLocator.css" type="text/css" 
media="screen" charset="utf-8" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></ 
script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 

<table id="storeListTable"> 
    <thead> 
      <tr class="even"> 
        <th>ID</th> 
        <th>Navn</th> 
        <th>E-post</th> 
        <th>Nettside</th> 
      </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr class="" id="store1"> 
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>Boss Store Oslo</td> 
        <td> <a href="mailto:">E-post</a></td> 
        <td> <a href="#">www</a></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr class="" id="store3"> 
        <td>8</td> 
        <td>Brandstad Oslo City</td> 
        <td> <a href="mailto:a@brandstad.no">E-post</a></td> 
        <td> <a href="#">www</a></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr class="even" id="store4"> 
        <td>7</td> 
        <td>Fashion Partner AS</td> 
        <td> <a href="mailto:b@fashionpartners.com">E-post</a></td> 
        <td> <a href="#">www</a></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr class="" id="store5"> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>Follestad</td> 
        <td> <a href="mailto:c@online.no">E-post</a></td> 
        <td> <a href="#">www</a></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr class="even" id="store6"> 
        <td>2</td> 
        <td>Follestad</td> 
        <td> <a href="mailto:d@follestad.com">E-post</a></td> 
        <td> <a href="#">www</a></td> 
      </tr> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

So.... could anyone give me a push in the right direction?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm not using jQuery to highlight table rows any more, but CSS.

This is for list elements, but I'm guessing this will work for table rows as well:

li:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #f3f3f3; }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this plugin http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/columnhover/

Here's how you use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#storeListTable').columnHover({ hoverClass:'highlight'});
    });
</script>
```

Take care

Comment: Thanks mate.

That's the plugin I ended up using.

Comment: works but old.  use the method background-color method from Julian.  note - ie is now about 1.5% (and shrinking) - and Mobile is about 7% (and growing_ - so which one to focus on going forward is easy :)

Answer (score 33):

If you don't need IE6 support, the highlighting can be done with some simple CSS:

```
#table tr:hover {
  background-color: #ff8080;
}
```

Comment: This is the default approach I'm using now (June 2012). Live and learn :)

Answer (score 5):

Is the alert message actually popping up when you test?

If so, it's possible the problem is with your CSS. It took me a long time to realise that most styles applied to a tr tag don't have any effect. So, in general, you need to apply styles to each td in the row

```
.highlight td {highlighted appearance}
```

rather than

```
.highlight {highlighted appearance}
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 wheresrhys. Using a background rule on `.highlight td` made your ‘TEST 2’ work fine for me.

‘TEST 1’ won't, because of the unnecessary `parents()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Once, I found this solution - works perfectly - just add!
Unfortunately, I do not know the author :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#table_id").not(':first').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css("background","red");
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).css("background","");
        }
    );

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this
[How to highlight rows in a table on mouse hover?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-highlight-rows-in-a-table-on-mouse-hover/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the solution of Julian with simple CSS is to be preferred. If you want to do it dynamically in javascript, you could do it like this

```
$('#storeListTable').on('mouseenter','div',function(){$(this).css('background','white');});
$('#storeListTable').on('mouseleave','div',function(){$(this).css('background','');});
```

If you have more divs per row, you could specify the div to be highlighted by giving each row class="row" and putting 'div.row' as the 2nd argument of on().