# How to highlight JSF row when the row is clicked

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have this JSF table:

```
<h:dataTable id="itemsTable" 
    value="#{SelectionBean.selectedItems}" var="item"  >

<f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="Items" />
</f:facet> 
<h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Select" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.selected}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="name" />  
  </f:facet> 
    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I want to highlight the row of the table when it's clicked. Is there a way JavaScript code to highlight the rows only if the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code you have show is a plain Java Server Faces(XHTML) code.So eventually it renders as HTML. In HTML if datatable renders at , with the help of jquery you could easily highlight it with the help of ID specified or selecting using the tag name. if you need help further with jquery on highlighting this link might be useful [jQuery highlight table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759475/jquery-highlight-table-row).

If you are using Rich faces by any chance you could use the rich:jquery tag to achieve the same instead of using a external javascript file.

P.S if you are using jquery using an external file with rich faces try to make use of the jquery.noconflict() method in your code as prototype.js in JSF may conflict with your code.

Good Luck!

---

**Update**

May be this code snippet could be helpful for you

```
<script type="javascript">

if($('.checkboxClass').attr('checked','checked')){

  $('tr').css('background-color','yellow');

 }
</script>
```

Comment: I saw the example. As far as I see it will highlight the rows when I move the mouse over them. I want when I click on the select checkbook the row to stay always highlighted.

Comment: I have added another code snippet to solve the select checkbox selection.

Comment: I tested the code - the entire table is highlighted. Not only the selected row

Comment: you need to specify id of the particular row using jquery for the row needs to be highlighted . It was a code snippet not the complete working code I posted.Let me know if you still finding it difficult to select the row ID