# How do you invoke the highlight affect (similar to mouse over) progmatically in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing an interface where there will be a list of wide buttons, I want to be able to highlight a button based on a mouse being moved up or down.
Selecting the button below the current highlighted button when the mouse moves down and selects the button above when the mouse moves up.

I was about to write a load of CSS manipulating Jquery code to do this, but something about doing that does not feel right.

Any suggestions welcome (including thats the way to do it fool)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759475/jquery-highlight-table-row

Comment: @tranceporter I wouldn't think so, this person needs to actually highlight a button in a direction of the mouse move, if I understand it correctly

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use the motion of the mouse to highlight a button. Effectively I am trying to change the way the mouse input is used to select a button, rather than moving the cursor over the button, I want the vertical motion to be used to select a button, with highlight of the button 'selected' moving up and down the sequence of buttons as you move the mouse up and down.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to highlight your button

**Example:**

```
button{color: green}
button:hover{color: red}
```

Comment: I was going to adopt a CSS highlighting approach, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this, after all doing it this way I will have to maintain the state of the buttons within my code. Is there no Jquery magic that can help?